# Briggs-Rauscher Reaction Temperature vs Oscillation Period

Tags: reaction-mechanism, kinetics

I am investigating the effect of temperature on oscillation period in the Briggs-Rauscher Reaction. By period I mean the average of the time the reaction to take one cycle (orange --> blue).

I have attempted to make a connection to the Arrhenius Equation with my data. However, I have no information about the rate constant and I am curious about how my period data connects to the rate constant.

Below is the graph I produced after assuming that the rate constant is linearly related to the period. Any insight on this problem would be very appreciated.
[image]

Comment: What period are you referring to exactly? The length of time between each oscillation gets shorter as the reaction progresses and eventually reaches equilibrium. You need to be careful to measure periods that are actually comparable. Also, what are the axis labels?

Comment: @jheindel Clarified the question.